# mysql selecting records for every n hour

Tags: mysql, sql

I have around 200,000 records and each record has DATETIME field. I have been trying to select records by every n hours using the DATETIME field. For example if n = 1; 1 record is selected for every 1 hour. I haven't been able to find many examples online.

Table: Product

Fields: id, name, description, lastSoldOn

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The description is rather vague.

Comment: I can't imagine a DATETIME field that will ever be equal to 1.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer great understanding, well done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can convert the date/time to seconds and use arithmetic to select one value from each n-hour period:

```
select min(datetimecol)
from t
group by floor(to_seconds(datetimecol) / (3600 * $n));
```

If you need the complete record, you can use `join` or `exists` to match back to the original table.

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I needed. Thank you. It's funny how people vote down a question when they don't know the answer.

Comment: @PRCube . . . The question is voted down because it is ambiguous (mine is not one of the downvotes).  I decided that this was the most likely reasonable interpretation, but the question could definitely be more complete.

Comment: It's downvoted because the way you asked the question it was open to interpretation.